# CSS Scroll Bar Problem

Tags: css, properties, height, scrollbar

I have used Accordion and Slideshow on my site. 
http://www.delightbranding.com/

when you click Play. For some reason the scroll bar appears shifting the page.

Guess i am missing setting height for some div. Please help.

Comment: Matijs. applied the below answers. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the height from `.control-next` css class

```
.control-next {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:201px;
    bottom:201px;
    /*height:432px;*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This one seems to be the bad apple:

```
<div class="control-next">
```

When the "Play" item is selected, this div expands below the HTML content, causing your page to grow.

Answer (score 1):

this is only happening for me in IE9 (I'd wager all versions of IE) and only when my browser window is short.

I tend to add a CSS rule to my html tag of

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Which places the scrollbar on the page always so that longer content doesn't make the browser behave inconsistently.

Not sure if this will help you in this case, but worth a try.